# "Night Light" in Windows 10 stopped working

Tags: windows-10

The "Night Light" in my Windows 10 doesn't work anymore.

I've tried opening the "Night Light" system settings app, and I select "turn on now" and the it looks exactly the same.  It doesn't matter how I move the Strength slider, the screen stays a glaring white.

I tried turning off the Power Toys applet (https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys), still the same.

I tried looking for a Night Light tile in my taskbar but I didn't find one (I found some web page saying to check there if Night Light is turned off).

Comment: Maybe they meant the action centre in the taskbar. Have you checked there?

Comment: First uninstall power toys and restart.  Then go to Settings, System, and turn night light on. Then go to Night Light settings and both Turn On Now and turn the Strength UP to make it more effective.  Works here.

Comment: I uninstalled PowerToys and didn't even have to restart -- Night Light started working immediately after I went to the Night Light control panel and turned it on.

Comment: Hi @pigeonburger -- yes, I had checked in the taskbar.  I didn't find Night Light there. Nor do I have Night Light there now. Thanks.  :)

Comment: Reinstalling PT worked for me, thank you!
@AlekseyTsalolikhin, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled PowerToys and didn't even have to restart -- Night Light started working immediately after I went to the Night Light control panel and turned it on